# Python 3.6 sleep() different sleep times within same string depending on character

Tags: python, python-3.x, sleep, sys

In python 3.6, I'm trying to get a string to print with a delay between characters and a longer delay for punctuation at the end of sentences to pseudo-simulate spoken English. Here is my code. My problem is that I get the delay between characters, but I don't get the longer delay between sentences.

```
import time
import sys


def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        if c != "!" or "." or "?":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            # If I comment out this flush, I get each line to print
            # with the longer delay, but I don't get a char-by char 
            # delay
            # for the rest of the sentence.
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        elif c == "!" or "." or "?":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(3)


delay_print( """
    Hello.
    I want this to have an added delay after sentence-ending 
    punctuation?
    But I also want it to have a shorter delay after each character 
    that isn't one of those chars.
    This is supposed to mimic speech patterns. Like if you've ever 
    played SNES Zelda: A Link to the Past.
    Why isn't this code doing what I want it to?.
    What I've written is broken and I don't know why!
""")
```

Comment: `if c not in "!.?"`

Comment: You could have easily debugged it yoursefl, for example by wirting `print('sleeping for 3'`). You wouldn't have seen it, so the first case runs always -> bad if expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `or` clause isn't doing what you think it's doing. The first one checks if any of these three things is True:

1. `character != "!"`
2. `bool(".")`
3. `bool("?")`

Note that 2 and 3 are always true.

If statements short circuit evaluate. If the character input were `.`, it would check condition 1 and find it false. Then it would include condition 2 in the evaluation `False or "."`. Since `"."` is always true, it short circuits and returns `"."` which evaluates to true. Try it yourself, type `False or "."` into the interpreter, you'll find it returns `"."`.

Personally, I would do this with a set implementation like this:

```
if c not in {"!", ".", "?"}:
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering obvious duplicates. If you think you can add a better answer to the canonical question at the end of the chain of duplicates, of course, please do that.

Comment: That fixed my issue! I knew that I just wasn't understanding the proper way this should be written. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Just to make sure you understand why what you had was wrong, consider the syntax the way you had it, but corrected to have the desired logic: `if c != "!" or c != "." or c != "?":`. To answer your other question, in any version of python a non-empty string is True. @tripleee trying to be nice since he's new, but I'll refrain. Also the SO you linked as a duplicate is also a duplicate :D

Comment: @sage88 Oof my mistake, thanks to your explanation, I see how this is exactly the same issue in the linked duplicates. I appreciate you taking the time to help me get it.

Comment: @sr71shark Happy to help. Going to delete this answer. Which apparently I cannot do because it's been accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the conditions that you are testing will always evaluate to `True` no matter what the value of `c`:

```
>>> letter == "!" or "." or "?"
'.'
>>> letter = "a"
>>> if letter != "!" or "." or "?":
    print("not punctuation")


not punctuation
>>> if letter == "!" or "." or "?":
    print("punctuation")


punctuation
```

As another user suggest it may make more sense for you to change your tests to:

```
>>> letter in "!.?"
False
>>> letter not in "!.?"
True
```

Also, on a more stylistic note I would consider using a random delay between letters to make it even more organic feeling.

```
import random

...

delay = random.random() + 2.5
sleep(delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot! Your first if statement needs to use 'and' instead of 'or', because it was always True.

```
def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        if c != "!" and c != "." and c != "?":
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(3)
```